# Adding data to a parcelable object passed to another activity

Tags: java, android

Right now I have three different classes that hold data. They're used to track grades. They are Class, Type, and Assignment. They all implement parcelable.

Now, when I pass a Class object to the Activity that represents a list of contained types, it works fine if the list of types is already contained the the Class object. However, when that activity is launched and I add data to it, it does not add it to the Class object such that when I backtrack to my Mainactivity and then click on the same Class object all of the data I've added in the other activity is gone.

Basically, what I'm asking is if you pass an object to another activity does it reference the same object in memory? If not, how do I make it so the information I add in the other activity becomes contained in the object I clicked on in the MainActivity which represents a list of Classes.

Comment: You can create static variables, they remain the same for every object of a particular class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically, what I'm asking is if you pass an object to another activity does it reference the same object in memory?

No. When you pass around `Parcelable` via `Intent`, runtime serialization/deserialzation takes place. It basically means that your objects are re-created with copied data.

This is also why `Parcelable` (or its lower level representation `Parcel` for that matter) is used as a fundamental data structure in Android's Binder driver to enable inter-process communication.

> If not, how

Since your `Class` class implements `Parcelable`, you can readily return a refresh copy of your data via `startAcitivtyForResult` and `onActivityResult` in your main `Activity`. You can find out more from [this developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Of course, you can always persist the data in memory or in file system when you exit the activity, and reload from persistence when your main `Activity` resumes.

Comment: So I was going to do that, but I actually start my second activity from the recycler view adapter. This is because the second activity is started by clicking on an element in the recycler view. Because I pass the adapter class the mainactivities context, I can only call startactivity, not start activity for result. Any ideas?

Comment: @KevinCianfarini Two ways I can think of now - one is to cast your `Context` into an `Activity` and call `startAcitivtyForResult` from there; another way is to use an event bus, and fire event when user clicks on the `RecyclerView` item, and listen for that event in your main activity. Then you can do whatever you want when such an event arrives.

Comment: @KevinCianfarini In fact you could just define your `OnClickListener` in your main `Activity`, and pass it to the `Adapter` as a dependency

Comment: Thanks those are very helpful!

Comment: @KevinCianfarini Most welcome! pls accept my answer if you find it helpful.